# Please clarify the problem with my question

Tags: support, closed-questions

My question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314451/how-do-i-tell-php-i-have-permission-to-access-its-parser was closed.

I find the lack of patience with a newcomer very rude!

There is a clear question here and it is on topic.  *If* it requires clarifications then please ask.  I'm doing my best to get up to speed in writing for CMS websites (Drupal) and PHP  coding as quickly as possible and have come to Stack Overflow with issues I have not been able to find answers for.  Instead of a little patience and support, the response from this site feels more like abuse for being ignorant. Furthermore, the stock explanation for closing the question is as vague as the Netbeans syntax checker I had the problem with.

As to the question, does this site provide support for an inquiry regarding working the Netbeans IDE?  I assumed that someone in the large following for this site would have encountered this problem and have some insight into where the program places its settings files.

Answer (score 16):

You're a PHP dev, right?  Don't you already know that PHP devs are a cranky lot?  Your question was closed by other users who are watching that tag, i.e., your fellow PHPers.

More seriously, there are a number of issues with your question.

1. It was slightly ranty.  `only to discover that the syntax checker is very poor`.  When you complain about the quality of stuff, you tend to attract downvotes and close votes from those who disagree with you.
2. You mention error messages, but don't include all of them in your question.  It is pretty common for new users to do this--say they have errors but then not include them, so this may trigger a downvote and/or close vote.  Its hard to figure out what is going on without this information.
3. Your question appears trivial to the point where it is off topic.  The crux of your question deals with a simple permissions issue--you don't have rights to file X?  The solution is to get rights to file X.  While it deals with a development tool (on topic), it appears like your issue deals with file security unrelated to the use of the tool.
4. You reveal, only in comments, that you can't find that file.  Before asking, you should have verified the location of the file.  If the file doesn't exist, your question should have been "Where can I get this?"  If it did, then you should have verified you have rights to access the file.  Your question would have then been about why the development tool isn't working correctly ("this error message is wrong!").

Don't take it too personally.  We expect our users be better than the average, and most of us older users have gone through the same thing you're going through now.  If it gets a little too rough for you, perhaps you should abandon the PHP community and come over to .NET?  MS devs (C++ not included!) are a much friendlier lot.

Comment: I'm just curious, so I hope you don't mind me asking... Did his question not have a chance over at serverfault? Just wondering, since I've seen posts move across stacks.. and I think it's great that there's such an option..

Comment: @Nonym: No matter whether the issue is file permissions or the development tool, ***it is not on topic at serverfault.***  Simple file permission questions should go to [su].  File permissions between two domains located in the same forest but one is a 2003 server environment and the other is 2008 belong on [sf].

Comment: Alright.. I see! Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: ಠ_ಠ Won't: Thanks for taking the time to respond. My response to items. 1.  Your right, as a beginner, obstacles keep piling up until frustration is maxed out.  To have such a prominent tool fail in basics caused my pot to boil over. 2. I did include the specific error message. 3. It is not trivial, I haven't a clue which software might be causing the error message, or how to give myself permission (I'm signed in as admin, I should have it already). 4.  Thanks for the tip, I will reword the question.

Comment: @JoeS: Yeah, being admin, that may not seem trivial (you must have permission to the file, right?).  But file permissions *are* trivial for users in our field.  Of course, some operating systems conflate permissions with existence, so you might get the same error message when you have no permissions for a file as when the file does not exist.  Figure that out and you know whether or not it is the tool (file exists and you have permissions) or if it is permissions.  The first you ask on [SO], the second you ask on [SU].

Comment: @JoeS: As for the error messages, you mentioned two--the ones you got when the file did not compile, and the one from the tool.  By the time you get to the second, a typical user may have already given up and cast their vote.  TL;DR syndrome.  Not much you can do about that, other than getting to the point early and often.

Answer (score 14):

> does this site provide support for an inquiry...

This is the nub of the issue. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site in relation to programming issues. It is not intended to be a "support" site for individual users. Many people are able to solve their problems by reading questions/posing a question of broader relevance that assists them with their own specific case. However, if the issue is something that is specific to your own setup of your server, as is the case in the problem underlying the question you link to, then it is highly likely that it will be closed as too localized/"not a real question". Clearly, from your perspective *you* have a question you want answered. The "real question" needs to be understood from the SO community's point of view.

All the best with solving your issue.